# Accessing TabControl from ContextMenu of TabItem

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid, tabcontrol

The number of rows in WPF dataGrid is in sync with number of TabItems in TabControl.
Please refer image [image: UI ScreenShot]
. Now When I click on Deleting a row in contextMenu of DataGrid .i.e., a TabItem also shall be deleted. To perform this operation I want to navigate to particular Tab-Control in Code and Delete the TabItem that is in-sync with DataGridRow.

So far, I am able to delete row in DataGrid but not able to delete particular TabItem from TabControl.

```
        //Code to Delete the DataGridRow from DataGrid Collection
        //Get the clicked MenuItem
        var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        //Get the ContextMenu to which the menuItem belongs
        var contextMenu = (ContextMenu)menuItem.Parent;
        //Find the placementTarget
        var item = (DataGridRow)contextMenu.PlacementTarget;
        //Get the underlying item, that you cast to your object that is bound
        //to the DataGrid (and has subject and state as property)
        var toDeleteFromBindedList = item.DataContext as IndHazardViewModel;
        DataContextHARAFunVM.HazardsCollection.Remove(toDeleteFromBindedList);
```

```
    //Draft Code to Delete particular TabItem from tabControl
    var target = (FrameworkElement)sender;
    while (target is ContextMenu == false)
           target = (FrameworkElement)target.Parent;
    var tabItem = (target as ContextMenu).PlacementTarget;
```

I want help with code to navigate from ContextMenu to TabControl.

Comment: If you have a viewModel collection for the TabItem then remove it from the collection. Else Remove it directly from the TabControl. What is blocking you now?

Comment: Even If I am deleting/ removing from collection, it is deleting the DataGridRow. But, to delete the TabItem from TabControl, I want that TabControl which I am not able to get.

Comment: Use VisualTreeHelper.FindParent(object) method in a while loop to find the TabControl

Comment: You can use VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tabitem) to get the TabControl

Comment: You claim that this is MvvM, then remove the dataItem from your collection in your View Model. If you have done it correctly, both Grid and TabControl will have the same `ItemsSource`. So when you affect one it will automatically update the other. How do you populate ItemsSource? Do you use Binding?

Comment: Thanks for the response! Using VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(tabitem) didn't help, as it would end up with null (). Yes, regarding ItemsSource, It's correct.

Comment: The `TabControl` isn't a visual ancestor of the `ContextMenu`. Is they in the same view or what's your setup?

Comment: Thanks for the response mm8. Yes, they are actually in the same view .i.e, the DataGrid is placed within one of the item of TabControl and I am trying to access this Tab-Control from ContextMenu of DataGrid. Also Please refer image.